# chrome extension - update tab without changing url

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm building a small chrome extension, that can open an page in a proxy
for example i'm opening www.mysite.com, and the clicking on my extension button, and it update the page to www.myproxy.net/q=www.mysite.com.
it's working like a charm, but i want to hide the chnage in the adress bar, so the url will remain the original site.
i made a few searches, but can't find out how to do such a thing.

can you please help me?

thanks

my manifest file

```
{
"name": "proxy",
"version": "1",
"browser_action": {
    "default_icon" : "icon.png"
},
"permissions": ["tabs"],
"manifest_version": 2,
"background":{
    "scripts": ["popup.js"]
},
"commands": {
  "_execute_browser_action": {
    "suggested_key": {
      "default": "Ctrl+B",
      "windows": "Ctrl+B"
    }
  }
}
```

}

my popup.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab){
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tab) {
    var newURL = "http://myproxy.net/?q=" + tab[0].url;
    chrome.tabs.update(undefined, {url: newURL});
});
```

});

Comment: Not possible because it would be a security hole otherwise, obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, this is not possible via [Chrome API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/api_index). The fact that you couldn't find searches means it's not doable yet. Unless maybe, you can write your own implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `history.pushState` or `history.replaceState` to do this. Refer to this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Example:

On the page of www.myproxy.net/q=www.mysite.com, add a script

`history.pushState( {} , '', '/' );`